# В чем ошибка при написании пути?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var rand1, rand2, rand3, rand4;
var myScore, compScore;
var image1 = new Image();
var image2 = new Image();
var image3 = new Image();
var image4 = new Image();

function randomNumber(from , before) {
 return Math.round(Math.random()*(before-1)+from)
}

rand1 = randomNumber(1 , 6);
rand2 = randomNumber(1 , 6);
rand3 = randomNumber(1 , 6);
rand4 = randomNumber(1 , 6);
randArr = [];
randArr.push(rand1);
randArr.push(rand2);
randArr.push(rand3);
randArr.push(rand4);



elem = document.getElementsByClassName('zar');

pic1 = document.createElement("IMG");


function roll () {
 for(var i = 1 ;i < 5; i++) {
  ('image'+i).src = '../img/'+randArr[i]+'.jpg';
  elem[i-1].appendChild('image'+i);
 }
}
```

```css
.container {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;

}

.container .header {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

.result {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
}

.name {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Zar</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="header">
   <div class="name"><h1>Zar</h1></div>
   <div class="result">
    <span id="comp">0</span> vs <span id="me">0</span> 
   </div>
   <button id="btn" onclick="roll()">roll the dice</button>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
   <div class="computer">
    <div class=" zar comp_zar_1">
     <!-- <img src="img/6.jpg" alt=""> -->
    </div>
    <div class="zar comp_zar_2">
     <!-- <img src="img/6.jpg" alt=""> -->
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="me">
    <div class="zar me_zar_1">
     <!-- <img src="img/6.jpg" alt=""> -->
    </div>
    <div class="zar me_zar_2">
     <!-- <img src="img/6.jpg" alt=""> -->
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function roll () {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('zar');
  for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = '../img/' + randomNumber(1, 6) + '.jpg';
    elems[i].appendChild(image);
  }
}
```

---

Результат выражения `'image'+i` в Вашем коде - не переменная (например, `image1`), а строка `"image1"`, у которой нет свойства `src` и которую нельзя добавить как HTML элемент в другой элемент.

Кроме того, в Вашем коде повторные нажатия на "roll the dice" не будут менять картинки, так как набор случайных чисел у Вас генерируется один раз.

Comment: а не подскажете в моем коде  ошибка в чем